# Why am I getting a NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, nosuchelementexception

This method is essentially a method that reads through a given input file and recursively populates a binary tree with the given information.

The input file is of a very particular format. One line that contains either Q: or A: to indicate whether or not the following line is a question or an answer. It is assumed that all files used with this method will follow this format.

Since every file follows the same format, and there should never be an odd number lines, the data shouldn't be fully consumed before reaching one of the `nextLine()` calls. Nonetheless, the program consistently throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
private QuestionNode readHelper(Scanner input){
    // Base case: If the given input has no more lines to read.
    if (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String category = input.nextLine();
        String text = input.nextLine();
        QuestionNode root  = new QuestionNode(text);
        if (category.startsWith("Q")) {
            // Recursive case: If there are still questions available to ask
            // more input is read, which replaces the currently stored data.
            root.left = readHelper(input);
            root.right = readHelper(input);
        } else {
            return root;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you have end-of-line character after the last line?

Comment: The best way to find out is to run your code under debugger step-by-step and examine values along the way.

Comment: Are sure that your file contains record with correct format?

Answer (score 1):

The second call to nextLine() within the if statement.  There is no guaranty there is a nextLine() after String category = input.nextLine().

Comment: There is a guarantee based on the files that I'm using, though. And those sort of files are the files that I'm testing with.

Comment: without viewing your files, a stack trace, etc. it's difficult to determine issues.  All I can do is look at your code and Java documentation - and according to the Scanner documentation, Scanner.nextLine() Throws:
NoSuchElementException - if no line was found
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed